# How to provide RTLabel and ScrollView height according to the content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, xcode5, html-parsing

I am creating an iOS article reading application for iPhone using platform Xcode(5.1) and chose template Empty application.

I am using `RTLabel` lib to parse html data in `ScrollView`.
Hyperlinks are not working.
I am facing a problem in Managing `RTLabel` height according to the content(content size is not fixed).
`ScrollView` contain `UILabel`, `UIImage` and `RTLabel`,it is working but i want to manage scroll height according to the content.

I applied this code but it is not working.

```
RTLabel *label = [[RTLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 400, 310, 600)];

[self->scroller addSubview:label];

[label setText:_DetailModal1[3]];

[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];

CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;

  for (label in scroller.subviews)  {

 scrollViewHeight += label.frame.size.height;   }

 [scroller setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, scrollViewHeight))];
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CGSize optimumSize = [label optimumSize];
       label.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y,      label.frame.size.width,optimumSize.height+10);
  scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroller.frame.size.width, label.optimumSize.height);